# What happens to the emf generated due to a change in magnetic flux in a coil?

Tags: electromagnetism, induction

When we move a magnet into a coil of wire (open circuit) and then out of it, we create a emf across the ends of the coil and another emf in the opposite direction. My question is what would happen to the net emf? Would it be 0?

This would be counter intuitive, because we obviously did work by moving the magnet into the coil, but the end result is no emf across the coil. Where did the energy go?